# how to plot a graph in pdf report in java web application

Tags: java, javascript, pdf, graph, jqplot

I want to generate a weekly report with graph in java web application. I am using jqplot as graph model to plotting graph to the user end.

but in my case quartz scheduler will run to generate the pdf with graph from a servlet, is there is any way to generate   graph image in background process i ll use that image to generate a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link for the answer:
 http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-pie-chart-bar-graph-in-pdf-using-itext-jfreechart/